# Avoiding commas in pandas print feature

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to limit the decimals printed in a pandas dataframe to 3 places using

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format
```

While it gets the work done, it introduces commas for thousands unnecessarily. For example, following is the output printed for the dataframe

```
        A     B 
1,817.121 0.381
2,180.545 0.343
```

How to achieve printing with required decimal places but without the commas?

Comment: If an answer helped you, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can locally override the program level settings. The formatting for decimals can be achieved upon using `float_format` in the following way:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write(df.to_string(index=False, float_format=lambda x: "{:.3f}".format(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**The 'commas' are thousands separators (in column A) that you actually specified** with [`pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)

If you don't want the thousands separators commas, just don't put them in the `float_format`!

```
>>> pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format
>>> df
          A     B     C     D
0 1,817.121 0.381 0.288 0.490
1 2,180.545 0.343 0.274 0.471
```

---

PREVIOUS ANSWER:
I assumed you actually wanted commas thousands separators, but just wanted to suppress the extra precision in column A.
Note that all four columns are float, but only column A is > 1000, or in fact > 1. So you'd only see thousands separators in column A.
Solutions/workarounds:
a) ideally you want to **apply `float_format` on a per-column basis**
b) less desirably, you could make column A a string, (but then you lose the ability to use it in numeric computations. Does that matter to you?)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = """A     B     C     D
    1817.121 0.381 0.288 0.490
    2180.545 0.343 0.274 0.471"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df), sep=r'\s+')

          A      B      C      D
0  1817.121  0.381  0.288  0.490
1  2180.545  0.343  0.274  0.471
```

Comment: I like the use of `float_format` way to achieve this as shown in my answer. The `lambda` function locally overrides the program-level settings.